# Python Selenium cannot find a way to scroll down (checked other responses an none seem to work)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to scrape the Kaggle rankings and the page is an infinte loading scroll. I would like to get at least the first 2000 ranked kagglers, and so to solve this I've created this script:

No matter what I do I don't see the browser scrolling and the lista_parseada list always has a length of 20. Can somebody help with this? Thanks!!

My code below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import date

# Notebook rankings url
url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/rankings?group=notebooks&page=1&pageSize=20'
wait_delay = 10 # seconds
scroll_pause_time = 2 # seconds

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument('-private')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)

# load page
driver.get(url)

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, wait_delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'site-content')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Loading took too much time!")

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
scroll_pass = 0

while scroll_pass < 10:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height 
    scroll_pass+=1

lista = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="button"]//div[@class="leaderboards__name"]/p/a')

lista_parseada = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in lista]

print(len(lista_parseada))

driver.close()
```

Comment: Page is not getting scrolled using   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to know why is that and how to solve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle has an api, so it's better to use it:

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


def post_call(url: str, headers: dict, data: dict) -> dict:
    response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/api/i/users.ProgressionService/GetUserRankings'

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cookie": "CSRF-TOKEN=VxwvCfDJ7O7KAEn8EWH0HeK9uT-G89SyETB0-hq9mZZhVsjDDIFJAh4OOhIUFjymST0kO8oX43sl86ZuOudHOoxHlPWV-krcTXNUlSgOQA;",
    "x-xsrf-token": "CfDJ7O7VujnuKA6ZuOudEn8ExwsAkR8eU_RQRaWH0HLuA2qYIkNHMeUOWequ-h2j0YuQNki8aAxC0j5tYvo9fI9fL-j9yzhevhI4MPdC9DRHLWnA"
    }

tdf = []

for i in range(1, 101):
    data = {
        "group": "ACHIEVEMENT_SUMMARY_TYPE_NOTEBOOKS", 
        "page": i, 
        "pageSize": 20
        }
    df = pd.json_normalize(post_call(url, headers, data)['list'])
    # use drop(columns=["value1", "value2"]) to exclude unnecessary values
    tdf.append(df.drop(columns=["thumbnailUrl"]))
# reset indexes
print(pd.concat(tdf).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output df with 2000 users:

```
      currentRanking        displayName   userId          userUrl         tier  points                  joinTime  totalGoldMedals  totalSilverMedals  totalBronzeMedals
0                  1       Chris Deotte  1723677         /cdeotte  GRANDMASTER    4943  2018-03-14T22:51:30.630Z             71.0               17.0                3.0
1                  2      Marília Prata  3012786         /mpwolke       MASTER    3621  2019-03-29T19:09:20.750Z             12.0               39.0              450.0
2                  3    Abhishek Thakur     5309        /abhishek  GRANDMASTER    3169      2011-01-12T03:44:52Z             65.0               28.0               24.0
3                  4            AmbrosM  7917824         /ambrosm  GRANDMASTER    2737  2021-07-16T18:36:58.170Z             28.0                8.0                8.0
4                  5           Y.Nakama  1695531  /yasufuminakama  GRANDMASTER    2630  2018-03-06T11:56:37.560Z             37.0                9.0                6.0
...              ...                ...      ...              ...          ...     ...                       ...              ...                ...                ...
1995            1996       ayoub chaoui  6625407     /ayoubchaoui       EXPERT      51  2021-01-30T15:31:19.840Z              NaN                1.0                6.0
1996            1997         micheldc55  6646082      /micheldc55       EXPERT      51  2021-02-02T18:58:13.170Z              NaN                NaN                5.0
1997            1998  Hugo R. V. Angulo  6910521     /hugovallejo       EXPERT      51  2021-03-10T18:29:25.247Z              NaN                1.0                7.0
1998            1999         Dina Nabil  7213495    /dinanabil811       EXPERT      51  2021-04-18T11:09:01.470Z              NaN                NaN                5.0
1999            2000    Naser Al-qaydeh  7424338   /naseralqaydeh       EXPERT      51  2021-05-15T13:16:16.093Z              NaN                NaN                8.0
```

Cookies and other info can be found on the "Network" tab in "DevTools"
In cookies you only need "CSRF-TOKEN"